# XAMPP mysql can't start after install zpanel

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have problem with my XAMPP, idk why but after install zpanel in my pc then XAMPP mysql cant start. I have uninstall zpanel and reinstal xampp, but still can't start.

when i start mysql, it will open confirmation box for Windows\SysWow64\net.exe.
and will show :

"12:58:40  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL service..."

but if i not confirm box, it will  show:

"12:59:18  [mysql]  There may be an error, return code: 1223 - The operation was canceled by the user."

I have try to change port in my.ini to 3307 and still can't start.
Whats wrong with my xampp? and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but in order to make the MYSQL to work I went to start to find the XAMPP and right click on choose to "Run As Administrator," on the XAMPP control panel it will show you a green check mark meaning another MYSQL is still installed and is running. Now, what you need to do is to click on the green check mart it will then ask if you want to delete the running MYSQL! You, should now chose "YES" after that, wolla... it will work from then on! Always run your XAMPP as an Administrator.